# Elasticsearch - "http://localhost:9200/?pretty" Not Working in IE - Shouldn't it?

Tags: rest, curl, browser, elasticsearch

In addition to using cURL, shouldn't I also be able to use IE and it display something directly in the browser with http://localhost:9200/?pretty since it's REST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this URL in browser, yes. Have you got an error ? Normally, you have a little json (elasticsearch version, etc i think)